# Using hsqldb with Ibatis to test a configuration that relies on Postgres in production

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hsqldb, dbunit

There is a current migration in the test environment to rely on DBunit + HSQLDB.  I am experiencing the `Nextval` issue.  My ibatis configuration file looks like so:

```
<select id="selectTestKey" resultMap="integerResult">
        select nextval('test_seq') as integer
    </select>
```

My Spring mapping file looks like so:

```
<bean id="testDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.syntax_pgs=true" />
        <property name="username" value="SA" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
```

Relevant Hibernate error:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error preparing statement.  Cause: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: user lacks privilege or object not found: NEXTVAL
```

This works correctly against an Postgres database, yet fails against HSQLDB.  The other answers on this site did not provide a solution for me.

Using the following maven config to get hsqldb:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: And why don't you test against PostgreSQL? It would be simpler and safer. Sure it would be slightly longer to execute the tests, but that's why continuous integration exists.

Comment: @JBNizet because there is no guarantee of us staying on PostgreSQL.  I do not believe my scenario is that out of the standard bounds of using DBUnit.  The issue is that it fails to run a test, which proves a dependency that needs to be resolved.

Comment: There is even less guarantee for you to stay on HsqlDB. The issue has nothing to do with DBUnit or a missing dependency. The issue is that you've written code supposed to run with PostgreSQL, at least for now. But you test it with HsqlDB, which has other rules, another syntax, other data types. If you test a formula 1 on an old small forest road, you'll find plenty of problems with the formula 1, but it's not supposed to ride on small forest roads in the first place. You should test the formula 1 where it's supposed to ride: on a formula 1 circuit.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes thank you for the contrived comment response.  You may not be aware of this, but `sql.syntax_pgs=true` which from the documentation: This property, when set true, enables support for TEXT and SERIAL types. It also enables NEXTVAL, CURRVAL and LASTVAL syntax and also allow compatibility with some other aspects of this dialect.  http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html  Unless I am misunderstanding the documentation.

Comment: @JBNizet All cars are tested in labs on various rigs before and at the same time as they are tested on the road. When developers use HSQLDB for tests, it does not mean they do not also test on the target database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEXTVAL, etc. all work in the Posgres compatibility mode. As you can verify by double clicking the hsqldb.jar and checking in the GUI DatabaseManager with your URL, a CREATE SEQUENCE statement and your NEXTVAL statement.

It is possible that the version of HSQLDB actually used is older than 2.2.8 and does not support the NEXTVAL feature. You can add a check to the URL, which results in connection failure if the database does not support the given syntax property.

```
jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.syntax_pgs=true;check_props=true
```

It is also possible that the full URL is not sent to HSQLDB, which would be the case if the above URL connects, but NEXTVAL does not work.

Comment: I see, and how do i force the full url into HSQLDB?

Comment: You would need to do this if the extended URL with the check_props=true does not fail. In that case find out what DBCP is doing with the URL, which I don't know much about. But try adding properties to data source definition, rather than the URL.